# Response from Web service using Apache CXF shows "No binding operation info.."

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, cxf

The problem description might be long. Please be patient and provide any kind of help since I am new to the web services.

**What I have done:**
I have created a web service in java using Apache CXF RI. I simply created a class and used bottom up development approach to generate SEI, WSDL and XML files.

**What the problem is:**
Now, If I request "`http://localhost:8084/DeepThoughtWS/services/DeepThoughtPort/whatIsTheAnswer`", it produces output as ***No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.***
The response is as follows:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>No binding operation info while invoking unknown
      method with params unknown.</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The generated `WSDL` is:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:tns="http://ws.service.com/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
name="DeepThoughtService" targetNamespace="http://ws.service.com/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://ws.service.com/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <import namespace="http://ws.service.com/"
      schemaLocation="http://localhost:8084/DeepThoughtWS/services/DeepThoughtPort?xsd=deepthought_schema1.xsd" />
    </schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="whatIsTheAnswerResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:whatIsTheAnswerResponse"
    name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="whatIsTheAnswer">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:whatIsTheAnswer" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="DeepThought">
    <wsdl:operation name="whatIsTheAnswer">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:whatIsTheAnswer"
      name="whatIsTheAnswer"></wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:whatIsTheAnswerResponse"
      name="whatIsTheAnswerResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="DeepThoughtServiceSoapBinding"
  type="tns:DeepThought">
    <soap:binding style="document"
    transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="whatIsTheAnswer">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input name="whatIsTheAnswer">
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="whatIsTheAnswerResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="DeepThoughtService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:DeepThoughtServiceSoapBinding"
    name="DeepThoughtPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8084/DeepThoughtWS/services/DeepThoughtPort" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The `DeepThought` class includes:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ws.service.com/", portName = "DeepThoughtPort", serviceName = "DeepThoughtService")
public class DeepThought {
    public String whatIsTheAnswer(@WebParam(name = "arg0") String interviewer) {
        return ("The answer " + interviewer);
    }
}
```

The console output at the time of request shows some errors too:

```
Feb 05, 2013 3:59:14 PM org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker invoke
SEVERE: Invocation without a binding operation.
Feb 05, 2013 3:59:14 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://ws.service.com/}DeepThoughtService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:168)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Feb 05, 2013 3:59:14 PM org.apache.cxf.services.DeepThoughtService.DeepThoughtPort.DeepThought
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 5
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 9):

> In general, this exception usually occurs if the incoming soap method
>   doesn't correctly match the WSDL. In such a case, the soap message
>   could not be mapped to an appropriate method on the service. CXF just
>   doesn't know what  to do. Double check the incoming soap message.

[Source of the above explanation.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201111.mbox/%3C2519604.d0hMIHgkpf@dilbert.dankulp.com%3E)

Possible solution:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ws.service.com/",
        portName = "DeepThoughtPort",
        serviceName = "DeepThoughtService",
        endpointInterface = "your.pck.DeepThoughtService",
        wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/DeepThoughtService.wsdl")
public class DeepThought {

    @WebMethod(action = "whatIsTheAnswer")
    public String whatIsTheAnswer(@WebParam(name = "arg0") String interviewer) {
        return ("The answer " + interviewer);
    }
}
```

What I would do is to add the WSDL location and endpointInterface in your `@WebService`. Also you are using Java-First approach so your method should be annotated with `@WebMethod(action = "whatIsTheAnswer")`. So if the method is not annotated `CXF` "understands" that your web service does not contain any methods at all and says: `No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.`

**See also:**

- [Developing a Service using JAX-WS](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html#DevelopingaService-DevelopingaServiceusingJAXWS)

Comment: I provided the WSDL location, endpointInterface and also the @WebMethod(action = "whatIsTheAnswer"). Still no response. Is my request correct "http://localhost:8084/DeepThoughtWS/services/DeepThoughtPort/whatIsTheAnswer" ?

Comment: What do you mean your request? This is the URL, not the request. If this is the endpoint of your deployed web service then you have send the SOAP request to it.

Comment: I meant URL. Can I get response from URL? The web service is working if I send SOAP request. But is there any way to get XML output using GET from URL?

Comment: This is not REST web service. SOAP services doesn't work that way. You can see only the WSDL file if you'd enter: http://localhost:8084/DeepThoughtWS/services/DeepThoughtPort?wsdl

Comment: Yes. But can't I make some of the methods that can be accessed with GET? 
Ref: http://www.java.net/node/696076

Comment: Good answer.  For the same exception just adding a WebMethod annotation to one of the implementation methods did the trick.

Comment: > But can't I make some of the methods that can be accessed with GET? If that's a SOAP service the answer is "No". SOAP runs via POST-requests!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Using cxf 2.6  2.7 This request by a web browser like chrome or firefox just didn't worked. I tried use a client did in cxf and it works! Your web services are working but you can't do a request by a web browser, you need a client since the cliente knows the requirements of the XML.

Answer (score 5):

Someone calls your `SOAP WebService` with `GET` request, but `SOAP WebServices` can not receive `GET` request. You should say to him/her don't call my `SOAP WebService` with `GET` request or call my web service with `GET` request like [described here](http://mywebservice.net/myapp/services/myservicepost01?wsdl).

Answer (score 3):

You should query using wsdl(like adding ?wsdl)at the end of url to check your webservice implementation works. Browser cannot send any soap request as a soap client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes already answered you can't directly access the service in a browser url. You need a client code like this

```
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean;
import org.junit.Test;


@Test
public void testWhatIsTheAnswer() {

    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    factoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    factoryBean.setServiceClass(DeepThought.class);
    factoryBean.setAddress("http://localhost:8084/DeepThoughtWS/services/DeepThoughtPort");

    DeepThought service = (DeepThought) factoryBean.create();

    service.whatIsTheAnswer("some answer");

}
```