# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown

Tags: java, web-services, apache

This error seems quite mysterious for me that what the actual cause of this error might create on the web service using apache cxf as ref implementation.

Please any one can help for error. My error message is as follows:

TQ in advance :)

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:198)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:168)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Please add code snippet

Comment: You might look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705362/repsonse-from-web-service-using-apache-cxf-shows-no-binding-operation-info